# NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask call two times

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm adding an event to the NSLeftMouseDownMask with this function:

```
mouseLefClick = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *leftMouseDown) {

     NSLog(@"!!");
```

}];

When I press first time it's call right but when I press second time the function it's call two times and all the other clicks it's going right except the second one. Please help me! Thx!